# Vertical align text to top of a div on Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I have a flex div with a div and a span, structure that I don't want to modify.

```css
.Flex {
  display: flex;
  background: lightgray;
  height: 300px;
}

.Square {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: black;
}

.Text {
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 40px;
  background: tan;
}
```

```html
<div class="Flex">
  <div class="Square"></div>
  <span class="Text">Title</span>
</div>
```

I'm trying to align the top of the "T" of the text with the top of the Flex div, something like the following image:

[image]

But I cant. `align-content: flex-start` will align all children to the top, but the text within the span will still have some distance to the top of the div.

How is possible to achieve this?

Comment: try letters like `ËÂ` and you will see that the text is already at the top

Comment: This is the correct. Please post it as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Add one property to your text's css: (you can modify this value according to the positioning of the text you would like, the higher, the more space the text has from the top edge)

```
line-height: 0.75;
```

```css
.Flex {
  display: flex;
  background: lightgray;
  height: 300px;
}

.Square {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: black;
}

.Text {
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 40px;
  background: tan;
  line-height: 0.75;
  }
```

```html
<div class="Flex">
  <div class="Square"></div>
  <span class="Text">Title</span>
</div>
```